# Filter blank cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter the columns which is not blank, however it doesn't work with following code:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("A:FE").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>", Operator:=xlOr
```

Also please notice that there are 6 rows on top of the header and I can't delete it for other purpose

I don't know will it affect the coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first 6 rows are blank then do not filter `A:FE`. Construct your range and then filter it. I guess you want to filter on Col L (Field:=12)?

Try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Sheet1 '<~~ Change this to the relevant sheet

    With ws
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> Assuming that Col A will have all cells filled up
        '~~> Else change this to the relevant column or use .Find
        '~~> to find the last row
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Construct your range
        Set rng = Range("A7:FE" & lRow)

        '~~> Filter it
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="<>"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: however after I filter <> then I want to copy visible cell to a specific column. I can do it using for loop but it takes times.

Comment: That is your 2nd question? I do not see that in your main question above? Also if you search stackoverflow, you can get the answer to the 2nd question. Try and search google for `visible cells autofilter`

Comment: yes i tried and i can autofilter "<>", however I can't paste the value correctly as when I copy the visible data, actually it seperates into different pieces, and I can't paste it directly

Comment: Copy and Pasting filtered results should go as a different question.